# linux/ubuntu - why "free" memory is not available?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory

Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
All resource intensive tasks run in docker.
Server with ~320gb memory.

Problem: **system is very unstable due to "cannot allocate memory" errors, but there is a lot of free memory**.

syslog:

```
Jul  4 21:16:01 seo2 dockerd[6190]: ... error adding seccomp filter rule for syscall getcwd: cannot allocate memory ..
Jul  4 21:16:06 seo2 systemd-udevd[7711]: Failed to fork: Cannot allocate memory
Jul  4 21:16:06 seo2 networkd-dispatcher[5617]: OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
```

vmstat at 21:16:05: ( **~100gb of free memory + ~30gb of available memory** )

```
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
19  0   4876 101314832 1515040 26962100    0    0     0 10544 99741 92965 38  9 53  0  0
```

/proc/meminfo at 21:15:58:

```
MemTotal:       329878428 kB
MemFree:        102057892 kB
MemAvailable:   122571380 kB
Buffers:         1515036 kB
Cached:         15812592 kB
SwapCached:           60 kB
Active:         101504768 kB
Inactive:       10301332 kB
Active(anon):   96766348 kB
Inactive(anon):  4165196 kB
Active(file):    4738420 kB
Inactive(file):  6136136 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:       4194300 kB
SwapFree:        4189424 kB
Dirty:             12660 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:      94459652 kB
Mapped:          7154140 kB
Shmem:           6879868 kB
Slab:           23807196 kB
SReclaimable:   11160972 kB
SUnreclaim:     12646224 kB
KernelStack:      384768 kB
PageTables:      1089868 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    334072728 kB
Committed_AS:   331331496 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:     18432 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:    154327872 kB
DirectMap2M:    177745920 kB
DirectMap1G:     5242880 kB
```

sysctl.conf:

```
vm.swappiness = 0
vm.overcommit_memory = 2
vm.overcommit_ratio = 100
```

**After i stopped every user task ( that i run in docker ), i still see that just ~200gb is free instead of expected ~300gb**.
But there is no any memory consuming running processes in the system.
After server reboot - everything is ok and 300+gb of memory is free.

How can that be possible that system apps fail with "Cannot allocate memory" when there is a lot of free memory?
Could you point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: Were cgroup limits set too small for your Docker containers?

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov no, everything ok with limits. Problem related to global system ( as you can see it from syslog i provided ).